# Copy and paste in Windows PowerShell

Tags: powershell, copy-paste

How do I effectively copy and paste input and output in the Windows PowerShell?

Answer (score 150, accepted):

- To select text in PowerShell with the mouse, just select it as usual.
- To copy the selected text to the clipboard you have to either hit Enter, or right-click.
- To paste into the PowerShell window, right click.

**keyboard**

- Paste: <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>[space]</kbd>, <kbd>e</kbd>, <kbd>p</kbd>

**Note:** In current versions of Windows 10, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> work as expected.

Comment: This is what I was missing, thanks!

To actually copy it is necessary to press Enter.

Comment: It is not necessary for me, but I have quickedit turned on in properties.

Comment: @orschiro: actually you don't need enter. I just tested it. You only need to highlight it and then right-click--> goes into clipboard. 
For pasting into powershell you only need to right click wherever you want.

Comment: right click to paste is not working on Windows 7 with PowerShell, seriously wtf

Comment: ok, it works, but it won't paste multiline strings, that's BS

Comment: you can also use the menu shortcut, `alt + [space] + e + p` menu->edit->paste

Comment: I don't understand how right-click can be copy as well as paste. If I click in the window to select it, right-clicking copies whatever I've selected. If I click in it, then press enter to clear the selection, it copies what I've selected. I guess I have to click the title bar in order to focus on the window without selecting anything for copying.

Comment: @SirDank It's "copy" when you have something highlighted, and "paste" when you don't.  Also, pressing Enter doesn't replace the selected text with "enter" -- PS's window just doesn't work that way, you can't replace selected text by typing.

Comment: Doesn't Ctrl+C interrupt and halt an executing command?

Comment: @mbomb007 Not if you have some text selected/highlighted when you hit Ctrl+C.

Comment: It does both for me, at least if I both have something running and something selected.

Comment: Nb! The menu shortcut will vary depending on the language version of Windows you have. On my Norwegian Windows install I must use `alt + [space], d, l`

Comment: `Shift + [Insert]` was much easier than `alt + [space] + e + p`, but now `Ctrl + c` works just fine.

Answer (score 16):

(Elaborating on the answer of Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 and Val)

## Mouse

*Select/Mark:* Press left mouse button, drag, release.

*Copy:* Right-click.

*Paste:* With content in the clipboard, right-click.

## Keyboard

*Activate Mark:* <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> > <kbd>e</kbd> > <kbd>k</kbd>.

*Select a Block:* Navigate (arrow keys, <kbd>Page-down</kbd>, <kbd>Page-up</kbd>, <kbd>End</kbd>, <kbd>Pos1</kbd>) to the upper left corner of the block, press and hold <kbd>Shift</kbd>, navigate to the lower right corner, release <kbd>Shift</kbd>.

*Copy:* With a block selected, either hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> > <kbd>e</kbd> > <kbd>y</kbd>.

*Paste:* With content in the clipboard, <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> > <kbd>e</kbd> > <kbd>p</kbd>.

Comment: +1 for the hint to "Activate Mark". I was searching combinations of Cursor and Caret but it always returned results for mouse cursor...

Comment: The *Active Mark* operation result in interesting behavior in pwsh 6.1 + PSReadLine 2.1.0. where the *Paste* operation, just insert the content at the current cursor position and not at the end of the last prompt.

Answer (score 6):

Depends on which PowerShell you are using.  With the newer [PowerGUI Script Editor](https://www.oneidentity.com/products/active-roles/) or with the PowerShell ISE (integrated scripting environment) cut/paste seems to work better:

- To cut drag the mouse across text to select, then ^C or right click to copy.
- To paste use ^V

With the older PowerShell:

- To cut drag the mouse across text to select, then enter to copy.
- You can sometimes hit ^C to copy but it does not seem to ALWAYS work.
- You can also drag to select then right click in the top window pane bar and select Edit | copy.
- To paste right click.

---

Good links for people learning PowerShell::

- **The best PowerShell tutorial** I've found so far is [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20160915062936/http://powershell.com:80/cs/blogs/ebookv2/default.aspx).  It goes into quite a bit of description of the command line.  Sadly some of the cool stuff in the original PowerShell appears to be broken in ISE, like ctrl-home for example, to delete to start of line.
- Some differences between these two PowerShells is [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2009/04/17/differences-between-the-ise-and-powershell-console.aspx?Redirected=true).

Comment: `Ctrl-V` also works in PowerShell on Windows 10 here (PS version 5.1.15063.296).

Answer (score 6):

As of PowerShell Core 6, shortcut to copy and paste is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> and is toggleable in the settings:

[image: PowerShell 6 settings]

Answer (score 3):

As of Windows 10, **Ctrl** + **C** works for copying the text & **Ctrl** + **V** works for paste. You can also select the data using **Shift** + **Arrow**(Left/Right).

The standard console can be used in Windows 10 — the PowerShell ISE is still available but not required for copy/paste support.

Answer (score 1):

Powershell functions like most terminal emulators (like PuTTY) - selecting text automatically copies it to your clipboard, and right-clicking pastes the content of your keyboard at your cursor.

Comment: Hello Rilgon, 

That was my first intuition but it does not work. Nothing gets copied to the clipboard.

Comment: That's strange, because I definitely just tried it myself just to make sure it was right, and it worked just fine.

Comment: Don't you need to hit enter to copy the contents to the clipboard in Powershell?

Comment: You just *select*, then `right-click` on the selection and it's in the clipboard. To paste, just `right-click` again.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to put the output of your command into the Clipboard, just use `Set-Clipboard` cmdlet as the final item in your pipeline, or its standard alias `scb`.

One caveat is that some commands return text (eg. `Get-Content`) and others produce collection of objects (eg. `Get-ChildItem`).  If you get weird things in clipboard, insert `Out-String` before `Set-Clipboard` to convert everything to text:

`gc .\myFile.txt | scb`

`ls c:\Windows | Out-String | scb`

Comment: This works well in a PowerShell console. Something that works in both PowerShell and cmd.exe is `type .\myfile | clip` and `dir C:\Windows | clip`.

Answer (score 0):

This is just to add a partial solution for those times you don't want to use the mouse. It only helps with pasting but you can press Alt+Space then e then p. The Alt+Space opens the PowerShell window's menu, the e opens the Edit sub-menu and the p does the actual pasting. Hardly convenient but it does save you from going to the mouse.

Answer (score 0):

To **paste**, you may use [AutoHotkey](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/autohotkey) script (this also affects all console windows):

```
#IfWinActive ahk_class ConsoleWindowClass
^V::
SendInput {Raw}%clipboard%
return
#IfWinActive
```

Found on http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/25590/how-to-enable-ctrlv-for-pasting-in-the-windows-command-prompt/.

Answer (score 0):

Another way:  highlight something, and control-mousedrag to copy it, in the Powershell ISE.  Alt-hightlight also highlights rectangles.

Comment: That doesn't work here.

Answer (score 0):

Select text with the mouse or Shift+Arrows
Ctrl+Shift+C to copy.

Comment: While we always appreciate new contributions, how is your answer really different from [this one](https://superuser.com/a/1184427/650163)?

Comment: It doesn't mention Ctrl+Shift+C